# Check value of a div within an embedded item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out 'how to' get the value of a div tag. The div tag is within an embedded item and not in the document itself. Below is the example of the embed code. The div within the embed that I’m trying to target is `final_result_score_text`.

I’ve experimented with `document.getElementById(id);` but it isn’t working because the div tag is inside of the embed, not the document itself.

When the page loads, `final_result_score_text` is empty. `final_result_score_text` receives a value after the embedded quiz is completed.

Can someone help me with the code or point me in the direction of a tutorial that will help?

Thank you!

**Entire Page Source**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.playbuzz.com/widget/feed.js"></script>
<div class="pb_feed" data-embed-by="09097896-3d12-4d72-9d63-e00c39c03f8d" data-game="/aaronw13/us-cities-trivia-questions" ></div>


</body>
</html>
```

**Screenshot from Embed**
[image]

Comment: Divs don't have value properties. Please clarify and show the scripting you've tried.

Comment: @Isherwood True, but they do contain data...I think the more important issue is getting the reference. You might be able to help show us the structure of the embed better using a browser's developer tools, given that it appears to be created by a JavaScript method. If you haven't analyzed closely, I'd say it's actually possible that it's not even doing it through an embed. Start by right-clicking the final result score (as it's visible in the document) and clicking Inspect Element, then try taking a screenshot of the surrounding HTML and posting it here.

Comment: @Katana314 I've updated the post to include the information you requested. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: you are setting the content of that div after an event occur or something like that it is right ?

Comment: @hamism Yes, the page loads and then the embedded iFrame loads. When the embedded iFrame loads, the content of the div final_result_score_text is empty. When the quiz is completed, the div final_result_score_text is updated to include a score (example 8/10).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're embedding a quiz from playbuzz.com. As such, the iframe being embedded into your page is on a different domain. There are cross domain security restrictions in place that will prevent you from accessing the iframe's contents via JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Do you know if there is another way to check the contents of a div from withing an embedded iFrame? The developer of the plugin suggested using Ajax.

Comment: It is possible to use ajax to create a proxy for accessing data across domains. However, I do not believe that will work in this case.

I attempted to use `file_get_contents` and `curl` in PHP, and `.load()` in jQuery, but was unable to retrieve HTML for the initialized quiz.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get a data of a div that is generated automalically and dynamically.
First solution you can use events to achieve your goal for example 
after the user clicks on the send or whatever button you're using to validate that quiz you get the content of that dynamic div

jquery example :

```
$('#validate').click(function(){
    var content = $('#target').text();
    alert(content);

});
```

second way is to use setInterval function(**i'm not sure this is a good practice**):

inside this setInterval function we check for the content of that div every period continuously.
so at the moment t = 0  the content of that div is empty

but at the moment t = x when that div has content in it, it get affected to the content variable

example :

```
var period = 1000; // 1000 = 1 second
var content = '';
setInterval(function(){
            content = $('#target').text();
},period);
```